# Как в Django создать базу данных заново?

Tags: django

Ковыряясь и пытавшись разобраться, я удалил в sql таблицу с моим модулем. Я не понимаю, как создать эту таблицу заново. Пытаясь разобраться в этом, я удалил еще несколько пунктов в других таблицах и теперь вообще все пошло по одному месту. Как мне начать работать с бд так сказать с чистого листа?

Comment: Общий принцип для всех БД - восстановитесь с резервной копии (надеюсь, она была).

Comment: нет конечно :) я же и говорю, как мне заново все создать, желания создавать весь проект заново нет. Но я не понимаю от какого момента мне переигрывать, тк миграции не создают мне таблицу модуля заново((

Comment: Было бы лучше, если бы Вы расшифровали "все пошло по одному месту". Базу можно удалить через консоль СУБД. В случае с sqlite вообще удалением файла.

Comment: @ReyD1 миграции у Вас в каждом приложении в папке migration. Их тоже при нежелании сохранить данные можно удалять.

Comment: я не могу добавлять в таблицу значения, тк самой таблицы нет. Я в чарме удаляю файлик бд, но он никуда не удаляется.

Comment: @ReyD1 если файл не удаляется - скорее всего он у Вас открыт в самом пайчарме и занят процессом. Отсоеденитесь от базы, и будем Вам счастье.

Comment: @ProtectchildrenofDonbas2014 спасибо, сейчас попробую

Comment: @ProtectchildrenofDonbas2014 все получилось, спасибо :)

Comment: Такая же самая проблема. Нашел ответ?